# What is the signal at around 2090 wavenumbers in the nitroguanidine FTIR spectrum?

Tags: ir-spectroscopy

There is a signal at around 2090 apparent in the FTIR spectrum of nitroguanidine  from Sigma-Aldrich (first image). It's also apparent in FTIR spectra we've taken in the lab (second image), but when assigning peaks to bonds, we are unclear to what it is.

We are unsure of how Sigma-Aldrich prepared their pellets, but we used KBr. We are thinking perhaps KCN, but then again - how could that possible form?

[image: nitroguanidine - from sigma aldrich]

[image: Experimental spectrum]

Answer (score -1):

Its common Nujol, a hydrocarbon oil used to prepare paste-samples for IR from powdered materials. Hence the C-H valence around 2090 cm-1

Comment: I doubt if a alkane like nujol or aliphatic kerosene would have a peak at 2090, there is a possibility that a peak in the range of 2090 could be due to the fact that the refractive index of sodium chloride disks and the nujol are different. You sometimes get some weak additional peaks due to this effect (it relates to the thickness of the KBr disk or oil layer)